# Is there a risk that managed components of an entity in D365 will be changed after some system update?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-crm-365

For example, if I add some more columns to managed view All Tasks, is there a risk that it will be reversed to the original columns after some system update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your solution is managed then there *shouldn't* be, as long as your customizations sit in a layer above the changes made in the system update.

However if your changes are unmanaged and Microsoft decide to import their patch/solution with **Overwrite Customizations** set to true, you may lose your changes [Source - MS Docs - Update A Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/import-update-upgrade-solution?view=op-9-1#update-a-solution).